# Load/Refresh WKWebView before opening/loading it

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How can I refresh/load all the contents of my .html page **before** the webview is opening/showing?

This is my code:

```
    class ContactViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var AboutWebView: WKWebView!

    let url = URLAddress()


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url = URL(string: "https://www.myfakeurl.com/about.html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        AboutWebView.load(request)


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }




}
```

How can i adjust that with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the web view until it's fully loaded and display it in `webView(_:didFinish:)`.

Note that you should conform your view controller to `WKNavigationDelegate`.

```
class ContactViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        [...]
        aboutWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        aboutWebView.isHidden = true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can i adjust your code with mine? I have posted the whole code above.. Can you please help me?:) thanks!

Comment: If you can adjust the code, i will mark this as the answer

Comment: @Ryan I edited my answer to include some details. You can easily append the code to your current snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help, it i got an error? and if i remove the  aboutWebView.delegate = self and build the app en preview in simulator i see a black screen.. see code: https://i.imgur.com/evmh8Rb.png

Comment: @Ryan My bad, edited the code. It's `navigationDelegate`.